# How to write piecewise function using anonymous function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to code the following function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} & x\neq 0 \\
      1 & x = 0.
   \end{cases}
$$

I am doing the following:

```
f = @(x) (sin(x)./x.*(x~=0) + 1.*(x==0));
```

However, `f(0)`returns `NaN`, while it must return  `1`.

Do you see what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that $\sin(0)./0$ is NaN, and multiplying by $0$ doesn't change that. 
The best solution is probably to use an .m file to write a function with an IF to deal with this.

One "hack" which "works" is by changing the function to evaluate at $x+eps$

> f = @(x) (sin(x+eps)./(x+eps))

Comment: We can deal with that with `isnan` in unnamed functions without the need to use `if-else` statement in a function file.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [an accepted answer in MATLAB answers](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/169709-substituting-a-number-for-nan-in-anonymous-function#answer_164712).

1. Define original function $f$ as `f = @(x) sin(x)/x;`.
2. Define target function $g$ as `g = @(x) [f(x) 1]*sparse(1+isnan(f(x)),1,1,2,1);`.

   - Example:

     ```
     x = .584; disp([g(x) sin(x)/x])  # return:    0.94412   0.94412
     x = 0; disp([g(x) sin(x)/x])     # return:    1   NaN
     ```
   - Exercise: Verify the above MATLAB code on (GNU) [Octave Online](//octave-online.net) thanks to free software technology.

---

## Remarks: Comparison with Julia

This is much easier in [Julia](//julialang.org), another open source language whose syntax resembles MATLAB and Python but [runs like C](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/).

```
f(x) = (x == 0) ? 1 : sin(x)/x
f(1)     # returns 0.8414709848078965
f(0)     # returns 1
f(0.01)  # returns 0.9999833334166665
```

- When $x = 0$, the conditional `x == 0` make `f` returns $1$, and the code after `:` is *ignored*.
- Otherwise, the rightmost part `sin(x)/x` is executed.